# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value dispatch-async

Tags: ios, swift, fatal-error, dispatch-async, optional-values

I am trying to implement loading data from Parse server after tapping a button on postVC to load data and navigate to guestVC. It was working fine and at some point began to crash the app...not sure why? I am getting the fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value...Any and all direction or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
import UIKit
import Parse

var postuuid = [String]()

class postVC: UITableViewController {

//postVC button click function
//clicked username button from post
    @IBAction func usernameBtn_click(sender: AnyObject) {
        let i = sender.layer.valueForKey("index") as! NSIndexPath
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(i) as! postCell

        // if user tapped on himself go home, else go guest
        if cell.usernameBtn.titleLabel?.text == PFUser.currentUser()?.username {
            let home = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("homeVC") as! homeVC
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(home, animated: true)    
        } else {
            let guest = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("guestVC") as! guestVC
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(guest, animated: true)
        }  
    } 



// guestVC relevant code
import UIKit
import Parse

var guestname = [String]()

class guestVC: UICollectionViewController {

    var uuidArray = [String]()
    var picArray = [PFFile]()

    // posts loading function
    func loadPosts() {     

            let query = PFQuery(className: "posts")
// app keeps crashing in line below when I try to load data to guestVC
            query.whereKey("username", equalTo: guestname.last!)
            query.limit = self.page
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock( { (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

                if error == nil {

                    self.uuidArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                    self.picArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

                    for object in objects! {
                        self.uuidArray.append(object.valueForKey("uuid") as! String)
                        self.picArray.append(object.valueForKey("pic") as! PFFile)
                    }

                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                } else {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                    // code here will be executed as the main queue

                })
            })

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a lot of exclamation marks to force unwrap optional values in your code, it's a bad habit. 
For example, you can unwrap  guestname.last safely by:

```
guard let lastItem = guestname.last else {
// do something else
return
}
query.whereKey("username", equalTo: lastItem)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. So what do I return in the else statement? I have a couple instances getting errors when I return a query using guestname.last when segueing to the guestVC.

Comment: The app crashes because guestname.las is nil (guestname is empty) but you try to unwrap it. In the else, you can handle the case when guestname is empty ( maybe display  an error in an alert view)

Answer (score 0):

Before adding or appending, check dictionary key has valid value or not. Check if 'uuid' or 'pic' key has value in dictionary or not. If it has then add/append.